# JHipster Maven liquibase:diff goal not working as expected

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys, jhipster, liquibase, one-to-one

I've added one-to-one bidirectional relationship to my entities.

```
|jhi_user| ----------- |project|
```

User:

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "owner")
private Project project;
```

Project:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private User owner;
```

Now I want to generate changelog as described [here](https://jhipster.github.io/development/) in section Database updates with the Maven liquibase:diff goal, but it does not work.

After my command  - **./mvnw compile liquibase:diff** - some wrong changelog is generated... Look below:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<changeSet author="danielpernik (generated)" id="1492075956240-1">
    <dropUniqueConstraint constraintName="jhi_social_user_connection_user_id_provider_id_provider_use_key" tableName="jhi_social_user_connection"/>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="danielpernik (generated)" id="1492075956240-2">
    <dropUniqueConstraint constraintName="jhi_social_user_connection_user_id_provider_id_rank_key" tableName="jhi_social_user_connection"/>
</changeSet>
```

It has nothing to do with my change and I really do not know what does it mean, because I did not never change table with name jhi_social_user_connection.

So am I doing something wrong or what does it mean? Thank you.

**UPDATE**
When I create my own changeset, add it to master.xml, it is not applied.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog>
    <changeSet author="danielpernik" id="1492077230363-1">

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="owner"
                                 baseTableName="project"
                                 constraintName="fk_project_owner"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="jhi_user"/>

    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Which version of Jhipster are you using ? I have experienced a few problems with liquibase:goal myself, and the solution is as simple as creating your changelog yourself. Don't forget to restart your spring back-end to take it into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. Application fires an error message after a long time.

Problem was not related to JHipster, but there was a zombie DB related process, which has my changelog locked for itself.

So in my case the solution was service reboot.